# commons.js incorrectly referencing HEAD instead of head

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm seeing an issue that has been mentioned before on the gmaps-api-issues tracker, https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/38295566, however there's no resolution to it that I can see.

When calling Google Maps JavaScript API, the common.js file that it returns has a line calling:

```
b.j.getElementsByTagName("HEAD")[0].appendChild(f);
```

This is causing the error "Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of undefined at new _.Xq (common.js:114)

All other references in the common.js file uses:

```
getElementsByTagName("head")
```

In the short term, what workarounds could I use to get this working until the common.js bug is fixed?

Answer (score 1):

There is a workaround in [the issue you reference](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/38295566):

> an additional HEAD element inserted by JavaScript, displays the map successfully, without any console error reported.

Insert an additional HEAD element using JavaScript.

```html
<style>
  #map {
    height: 100%;
  }
  html,
  body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }
  HEAD {
    display: none;
  }
</style>
<script>
  document.documentElement.appendChild(document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml', 'HEAD'));
</script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="map"></div>
  <script>
    var map;

    function initMap() {
      map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        center: {
          lat: -34.397,
          lng: 150.644
        },
        zoom: 8
      });
    }
  </script>
  <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=initMap" async="async" defer="defer"></script>
```